# Wait Serial response from magstrip card

Tags: python, magnetic-cards

I'm new programing in Python, and what I need a little help with this little  aplication.

I write a little aplication that generate a random code and write it to the magstrip card.

The card reader is a MSR206u and is connected by serial port, I can read & write to the card encoder, but I need to wait for the confirmation from the encoder.

When I send to the encoder to write, it write OK, but I dont know how to "wait" to the response from the encoder.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please provide some details on how you are communicating with the card reader.

Comment: Hi, I connected using a serial cable in Linux, and in Windows I use a USB cable that create a virtual COM port. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for the response by simply doing a read on the serial port with an appropriate timeout configured. Both the read and inter-character timeouts may be specified in the constructor of the [serial.Serial class](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#classes) from [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I was using the pyserial module and after a lot of test, I find that alone!! Thanks again!!